# Publish pending article from front end with a button?

Tags: posts, php, front-end, publish

Is it possible to take the blue publish button in back end of the wordpress and place it in the frontend near the post in my index.php. I need a way to publish the pending article without going to dashboard and only admin can see the publish button?

```
<?php   
$args=array(
'post_type'         => 'post',
'post_status'       => 'pending',
'order'                 => 'ASC',
'caller_get_posts'  =>1,
'paged'         =>$paged,
            );
```

Thank You all in advance for help :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First create a function that will print the publish button :

```
//function to print publish button
function show_publish_button(){
    Global $post;
    //only print fi admin
    if (current_user_can('manage_options')){
        echo '<form name="front_end_publish" method="POST" action="">
                <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="'.$post->ID.'">
                <input type="hidden" name="FE_PUBLISH" id="FE_PUBLISH" value="FE_PUBLISH">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Publish">
            </form>';
    }
}
```

Next create a function to change the post status:

```
//function to update post status
function change_post_status($post_id,$status){
    $current_post = get_post( $post_id, 'ARRAY_A' );
    $current_post['post_status'] = $status;
    wp_update_post($current_post);
}
```

Then make sure to catch the submit of the button:

```
if (isset($_POST['FE_PUBLISH']) && $_POST['FE_PUBLISH'] == 'FE_PUBLISH'){
    if (isset($_POST['pid']) && !empty($_POST['pid'])){
        change_post_status((int)$_POST['pid'],'publish');
    }
}
```

Now all of the above code can go in your theme's functions.php file and all you have to do is add `show_publish_button();`  in your loop of pending posts after each post.

Comment: Glad i could help.

Comment: Is it possible to have a different name on the buttom? Like submit instaead of publish..

Comment: Of course just change the 'value' of the submit button.

Comment: Sorry for reviving this old topic @Bainternet but using this code on a test I'm doing is taking me to the wordpress error page "Are you sure you want to do this? Please try again". The post is actually published but it's going to that page for some reason. I'm using Membership plugin and 'manage_options' is active on that user role. Thanks.

Comment: @Bainternet sorry the plugin I'm using is Members not Membership.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! Worked fine.