# Function is Missing an Action Hook

Tags: hooks, front-end, post-status, post-meta

I have tied an action into a status change, which works on the backend. However,using a frontend button for updating post status does not trigger the action(http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17794/publish-pending-article-from-front-end-with-a-button), but it does update the post status.

So I have this button for updating a post from 'draft to rejected'

```
     function show_reject_button(){
       global $post;

        echo '<form name="front_end_reject" method="POST" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="pid2" id="pid2" value="'.$post->ID.'">
            <input type="hidden" name="FE_REJECT" id="FE_REJECT" value="FE_REJECT">
            <input type="image" src="https://---.com/images/logo1/sreject.png" alt="reject" title="Reject this reservation" style="background: none !important; border:   none !important;">
        </form>';
       }

    function change_post_status($post_id,$status){
      $current_post = get_post( $post_id, 'ARRAY_A' );
      $current_post['post_status'] = $status;
      wp_update_post($current_post);
     }  

   if (isset($_POST['FE_REJECT']) && $_POST['FE_REJECT'] == 'FE_REJECT'){
     if (isset($_POST['pid2']) && !empty($_POST['pid2'])){
    change_post_status((int)$_POST['pid2'],'rejected');
     }
    }
```

I'd like to thank Bainternet for that code.

I have the action of changing a post from draft to rejected tied into a function for changing some post meta.

```
      add_action ('draft_to_rejected', 'void_payment_hold' );   
      function void_payment_hold() {

     global $post;

      $type = get_post_type( $post->ID );

        if( $type == 'tribe_events' ){

            $order_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'order', TRUE);

            $current_hold = get_post_meta($order_id, 'hold', TRUE);

            $released_amount = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'amount', TRUE);

            $remaining_hold = $current_hold - $released_amount;

            __update_post_meta($order_id, 'hold', $remaining_hold);     

         }

       }
```

When I execute this on the backend it works, but when I update the post status with the button the function does not execute. Does anyone know why this may be happening?

Thanks for your time

Comment: I also tried adding do_action("draft_to_rejected"); to the button but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly 'solved' -- I still do not know why wp_update_post() did not hit the transition of {old status}*to*{new status}

For my situation I simply added the below function to a unique instance of the button above. Not ideal, but hey it works.