# How to add publish/draft button in Admin Post Lists

Tags: functions, admin-menu

I try to add publish/draft button in Wordpress Admin Post Lists but it doesn’t work well in a certain situation.

**Does Not Work**

New post -> Save as Draft -> Publish using new button in Adomin Post Lists

**Does Work**

New post -> Publish -> Draft -> Publish using new button in Adomin Post Lists

Thank You all in advance for help or any other ways :D

> Reference :
>   [Publish pending article from front end with a button?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17794/publish-pending-article-from-front-end-with-a-button)
>   (this doesnt work)

Here’s functions.php code

```
function show_publish_button($post_id){
$pub_form = <<<EOF
        <form name="make_it_publish" method="post" action="">
                <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="{$post_id}">
                <input type="hidden" name="mi_publish" id="mi_publish" value="mi_publish">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="publish">
         </form>
EOF;
echo $pub_form;
}

function show_draft_button($post_id){
$pri_form = <<<EOF
        <form name="make_it_draft" method="post" action="">
                <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="{$post_id}">
                <input type="hidden" name="mi_draft" id="mi_draft" value="mi_draft">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="draft">
         </form>
EOF;
echo $pri_form;
}

function change_post_status($post_id,$status){

    $time = current_time('mysql');
    wp_update_post(
        array(
           'ID'                         =>  $post_id,
           'post_status'        =>  $status,
           'post_name'          =>  $post_id,
           'post_date_gmt'  =>  get_gmt_from_date( $time )
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'admin_init', function() {
    if (isset($_POST['mi_publish']) && $_POST['mi_publish'] == 'mi_publish'){
        if (isset($_POST['pid']) && !empty($_POST['pid'])){
            change_post_status((int)$_POST['pid'],'publish');
        }
    }
    if (isset($_POST['mi_draft']) && $_POST['mi_draft'] == 'mi_draft'){
        if (isset($_POST['pid']) && !empty($_POST['pid'])){
            change_post_status((int)$_POST['pid'],'draft');
        }
    }
});


function manage_posts_columns($columns) {
    $columns['publish'] = "publish";
    $columns['draft'] = "draft";
    return $columns;
}

function add_column($column_name, $post_id) {

    if($column_name == 'publish'){
        $pub = "publish";
    }
    if($column_name == 'draft'){
        $pri = "draft";
    }


    if ( isset($pub) && $pub ){
        show_publish_button($post_id);
    } else if ( isset($pri) && $pri ){
        show_draft_button($post_id);
    } else {
        echo __('None');
    }
}
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'manage_posts_columns' );
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'add_column', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is **nest** form tag.

Admin Post Lists is huge form and I added form tag. That's why it didn't work.

Simple way is using ajax and wp_update_post.